# Fine Uploader continuously retries, ASP.Net not MVC

Tags: asp.net, fine-uploader

I'm using an Azure Web Role (not MVC) ApiController to receive FineUploader requests. It works fine (!) -- files successfully upload -- except that the response does not seem to be what the client is expecting. I'm using the `PostFormData` method in the controller and have adapted the sample ASP.Net MVC code.

This is the server-side code:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFormData()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }
        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

        try
        {
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // Show all the key-value pairs.
            foreach (var key in provider.FormData.AllKeys)
            {
                foreach (var val in provider.FormData.GetValues(key))
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", key, val));
                }
            }
            //what should this be? 
            HttpResponseMessage hm= Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new FineUploaderResult(true, new { extraInformation = 12345 }));
            return hm; 
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
        }
    }
```

I've tried JSON-serializing the `FineUploaderResult` to no avail and also as part of that tried making the members of that class public so that `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` would include them. But there's something the client-side just doesn't like.

EDIT: here is the console log from Chrome:

```
 [Fine Uploader 5.16.0] Sending simple upload request for 0 fine-uploader.js:162 
 [Fine Uploader 5.16.0] xhr - server response received for 0 fine-uploader.js:162 
 [Fine Uploader 5.16.0] responseText = {} fine-uploader.js:162 
 [Fine Uploader 5.16.0] Received response status 200 with body: {} fine-uploader.js:162 
 [Fine Uploader 5.16.0] Simple upload request failed for 0
```

Comment: your server isn't returning anything in the response payload - see https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/endpoint_handlers/traditional.html

Comment: perfect, thanks very much, exactly what i was looking for. At the risk of violating SO's rules, another question, is there a way to specify to the server the desired path of the uploaded file?

Comment: found it. `params`. works like a charm.